# Display a picture from a PHP script calling wit $_GET id

Tags: php

I want to display (or better download) a file (photo, Excel, PDF) from a directory outside www.

my wwww :

all my site excecpt some documents

private/carte_identites :

documents outside wwww (just before the www)

I tried to code the calling and the function

```
<?php $image='../private/services/getFile.php?id=test';
echo "<img src='".$image."' width='200'/>"; ?>

    <?php


if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == 'administration')
    {
        //echo "inclusion ok";
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
        {
            $filter = stripslashes($_GET['id']);
            $extension = substr($filter,-3);
            $path =  'private/cartes_identites/' . $filter;
            if($extension =='gif') header("Content-type: image/gif");
            elseif($extension =='jpg') header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            elseif($extension =='png') header("Content-type: image/png");
            echo file_get_contents($path);
        }
    }


?>



I should get a picture, I have nothing
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: nothing unfortunately...

Comment: Can you add an `else` to your `if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == 'administration')` condition to see if this is why you are getting nothing? And an `else` to your `if(isset($_GET['id'])` condition as well?

Comment: Thank you.  I do not enter in the function because the function is out of the www, and my call is /home/web998/public_html/ script (mysite.com/myscript) but I should go to a directofy before /home/web998/private/services/myscript, outside public_html